# Normalize document captured from camera in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I want to use a camera as a Document Scanner and I need to fix the distortion.
I have seen solutions that allow the user to point on the corners of the document, and they fix the distortion according the points.
I am trying to do that with OpenCV, but I cannot find a simple way to do that.
Can somebody show me how o do that with simple 4 corners of the document?

Thank's
Meir

Comment: I found the solution here: http://nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/3414/ that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here: [nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/3414](http://nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/3414/) that's exactly what I was looking for.